# Is change of pH of water with respect to temperature linear?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, water, ph, temperature

Only recently I learned that the pH of water [varies with temperature,](https://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry/Acids_and_Bases/Acids_and_Bases_in_Aqueous_Solutions/The_pH_Scale/Temperature_Dependence_of_the_pH_of_pure_Water) from about 7.47 at 0 °C to 6.14 at 100 °C.

My question is, first, is there a geometric explanation for this, in the sense that water can perhaps arrange itself in a way that partial bonding of oxygen to a third hydrogen can happen without simultaneously producing hydroxide ions to balance things out?

And--related--is the spread of pH above enough to create a detailed profile for the variation of pH with temperature? If so is it linear?

Comment: Note that the change in pH does not necessarily mean that the solution is not neutral, only that the dissociation increases at higher temperature.

Comment: The variation of pH with temperature is for pure water so $\ce{[H^+] = [OH^-]}$, or in other words the water remains "neutral".

Comment: basic means $\ce{[OH^-] > [H^+]}$, acidic means that $\ce{[H^+] > [OH^-]}$, and neutral means $\ce{[OH^-] = [H^+]}$

Comment: Water isn't really unique in that sense. The pKa  of acids and the pKb of bases will vary with temperature. We just normally assume everything is at "room" temperature. For water curve see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_(data_page)#Self-ionization

Comment: Re: **basicity means [OH−]>[H]+], i.e., a preponderance of [OH−] in a "neutral" solution.** No if $\ce{[OH^-] > [H^+]}$ then the solution is basic. A neutral solution has $\ce{[OH^-] = [H^+]}$. But because of the temperature variation the autoionization constant  of water isn't a "constant" but changes with temperature. But again for all temperatures *pure water* will be neutral and it will have $\ce{[OH^-] = [H^+]}$.

Comment: @MaxW: Yes, I see now you are saying the water is neutral. I will delete some of my comments as a matter of housekeeping. Appreciate the comments.

Comment: Don't delete comments or the whole series of comments don't make sense...

Comment: Your comments are perfectly understandable and incorporate my (erroneous) assumptions. @Zhe's initial response also indicates the nature of my confusion. At this point I can at least articulate the confusion--that water may be "neutral" but still have a pH above/below 7. Is this correct?

Comment: Is the downvote to punish me for deleting comments?! Tough crowd!

Comment: "water may be "neutral" but still have a pH above/below 7" I think you've got it now.

Comment: @Zhe: Thanks--it is a new idea to me and I still have to process it, but appreciate the help.

Comment: $\text{pH} = -\log{ \ce{[H+]}}$ so the $\text{pH}$ doesn't depend on $\ce{[OH^-]}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize... in aqueous solutions:

- Basic means $\ce{[OH−] > [H+]}$
- Acidic means that $\ce{[H+] > [OH-]}$
- Neutral means $\ce{[OH−] = [H+]}$

There is a for the Wikipedia article for the [autodissociation of water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water). The  chemical equation for the autodissociation is:
$$\ce{H2O <=> H^+ + OH^-}$$
The mathematical relationship between $K_d^t$, $\ce{[H^+]}$, $\ce{[OH^-]}$ and $t$ is: $$K_d^t =\ce{[H+][OH-]}\quad\text{for }t > 32\text{ C}$$
Note that $K_d^t$ changes with temperature $t$, but for pure water at any temperature, $t$,  the water will be neutral, and $\ce{[OH−] = [H+]}$. The temperature dependency of $K_d^t$ also means that pH + pOH is not always 14.

The Wikipedia article shows that the [relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water#Dependence_on_temperature.2C_pressure_and_ionic_strength) between $K_d^t$ and temperature is a curve. (The curve shown is a bit odd in that water boils at 100 C, so higher temperatures must be taken under pressure.)

Also regardless of temperature the $\text{pH}$ of an aqueous solution is defined as $\text{pH} = -\log{\ce{[H^+]}}$ so the pH does not depend on $\ce{[OH^-]}$.

Comment: This is a good summary of the comment discussion. Can you also address the main question of the post? Do we know whether the change in pH is linear over that interval? +1.

Comment: Oh--I do have a question--the pH does not depend on $[OH^-]$? But doesn't pH+pOH=14? That is an explicit dependence.

Comment: @Danial - No, that is the point. pH + pOH is not always 14 for a neutral solution since $K_d^t$ changes with temperature. If $\ce{[H^+] = [OH-]}$ then $K_d^t = [H^+]^2$ and $pK_d^t = 2 \times \text{pH}$

Comment: Thanks, somehow I missed the picture. This is I think a good (and complete) answer. Appreciate your patience with my questions! Will accept this very shortly.